# Validating (required=true) set in JsonProperty while using ObjectMapper in Jackson should throw Exception

Tags: java, validation, jackson, jackson2, jackson-databind

I am trying to use Jackson library for deserialization since I have a scenario wherein I have to validate for `null` values in many JsonProperty if it is set as `required=true`.

Here is the code snippet.

```
public class JacksonValidator {
    private static final ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Should succeed since all properties have value and required=true holds good
        validate("{\"id\": \"1\",\"age\": 26,\"name\": \"name1\"}");

        // Should throw exception since name is null (because of required=true)
        validate("{\"id\": \"2\",\"age\": 28,\"name\": null}");

        // Should throw exception since id is null (because of required=true)
        validate("{\"id\": null,\"age\": 27,\"name\": \"name2\"}");
    }

    public static void validate(String json) {

        try {
            Customer customer = MAPPER.readValue(json, Customer.class);
            System.out.println(customer);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw new DeserializationException(String.format("Validation failed. Unable to parse json %s", json), e);
        }
    }

    @Setter
    @Getter
    @ToString
    public static class Customer {
        private String id;
        private Integer age;
        private String name;

        @JsonCreator
        public Customer(@JsonProperty(value = "id", required = true) String id,
                @JsonProperty(value = "age", required = false) Integer age,
                @JsonProperty(value = "name", required = true) String name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.age = age;
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see in the above code, I am trying to deserialize `JSON` into `Customer` class. If the `required` property is set to `true` for a `JsonProperty` and while deserialization if this property encounters `null`(for `id` and `name` field in the above code), I have to throw a custom `DeserializationException`.

And also I need to have `null` values processed(shouldn't fail) for fields where `required=false` is set in JsonProperty(for `age` field).

Here I cannot use `MAPPER.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` since I need to process `null` values for `required=false` fields.

Please let me know how this could be achieved using `ObjectMapper.readValue` method or any other method that holds good here.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `@JsonProperty` for null validation. It only checks whether value is present or not. From [javadocs](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html#required())

> Property that indicates whether a value (which may be explicit null) is expected for property during deserialization or not.

For null validation you can use Bean validation JSR-380. Hibernate example:

Maven dependencies:

```
<!-- Java bean validation API - Spec -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Hibernate validator - Bean validation API Implementation -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.11.Final</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Verify validation annotations usage at compile time -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.11.Final</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Unified Expression Language - Spec -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1-b06</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Unified Expression Language - Implementation -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Then you can use it like:

```
ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
Set<ConstraintViolation<Customer>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(customer);
if (constraintViolations.size() > 0) {
    throw new DeserializationException(String.format("Validation failed. Unable to parse json %s", json), e);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I don't think Bean Validation works for `@JsonProperty` or any other Jackson Annotations. It only works for fields with `javax.validation.*` for eg annotations marked with `@NotNull` etc. I tried this out sometime back too. In my case, I can't change the `Customer` class at all. That is how it would be generated and I have to use it

Comment: @DMA You're right it only works for `javax.validation.*` JSR-380. If you can't change `Customer` class, I think you should try with reflection or some annotation processor validator, if performance is crucial.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply @SukhpalSingh. Yes, you are right. Here performance is crucial too. Yes, one option as you mentioned is with reflection. Is there any other way of doing it? Is it possible to create a schema out of this `Customer` class for eg and then validate it with Jackson or any other library?